# Function and if else statement not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I am just learning how to code and I am working on fundamentals right now using CodeWars for practice. Since CodeWars allows you to look at solutions, I looked at a few for guidance, which was helpful. I have used this site for guidance but can't figure out why my function isn't working. It is written in javascript. It outputs only []. Here is the problem, code, and the output (in order below):

## Problem

> *Write a method, that will get an integer array as parameter and will process every number from this array.
>   Return a new array with processing every number of the input-array like this:
>   If the number has an integer square root, take this, otherwise square the number.
>   [4,3,9,7,2,1] -> [2,9,3,49,4,1]*

## CODE

```
function squareOrSquareRoot(array) {

    var newValues = []; // new array for new values

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ // for loop to look through the values

        var initial = array[i]; // extracting one value from the array to evaluate
        var sqrt = Math.sqrt(initial); // finding the square root of initial
        if (Number.isInteger(sqrt) == 'true'){ // determining if sqrt is an integer 
                                            // and if so .....
            newValues.push[sqrt];
        } // .... adding sqrt to the newValues array
        else if (Number.isInteger(sqrt) == 'false') { // determining if sqrt is not 
                                                      // an integer
            newValues.push[initial*initial];  // then multiplying initial by itself 
                                           //and adding to newValues
        }
    }
    return newArray; // returning newValues onto the screen
}
```

## OUTPUT

```
Expected: '[2, 9, 3, 49, 4, 1]', instead got: '[]'

Expected: '[10, 10201, 25, 25, 1, 1]', instead got: '[]'

Expected: '[1, 4, 9, 2, 25, 36]', instead got: '[]'
```

Comment: if the answer resolved the issue then please accept the answer, if you need more help please leave a comment so we can help you.

Comment: Do you strictly have to use for loop? If not check out my answer it's actually everything you need. It uses the `Array.map` function with is a better choice in this case IMO

Comment: I do not have to use a for loop but I have only been studying for 4 weeks and want to learn to use use for loops better. BTW, I really like your answer for its simplicity. I hope to write code like that one day soon.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are doing a lot of stuff wrong.

1. You are not returning correct array. You should return `newValues` instead of `newArray`.
2. You should not use quotation marks for `true` or `false`
3. Using if/else if for true/false is not necessary. Use if/else instead

Here is working solution:

```
function squareOrSquareRoot(array) {

    var newValues = []; 
    for(var i = 0 ; i<array.length ;i++) {
        Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(array[i]))?newValues.push(Math.sqrt(array[i])):newValues.push(array[i]*array[i]);
    }
    return newValues;
}

var a = [3,4,5,9,7,16,36,11];
console.log('Input : ' + a);
console.log('Output: ' + squareOrSquareRoot(a));
```

> Input : [3,4,5,9,7,16,36,11]
>
> Output: [9,2,25,3,49,4,6,121]

If this ternary expression is confusing you, here is example with if/else statement:

```
function squareOrSquareRoot(array) {

    var newValues = []; 
    for(var i = 0 ; i<array.length ;i++) {
        var initial = array[i];
        var sqrt = Math.sqrt(initial);
        if(Number.isInteger(sqrt)) 
            newValues.push(sqrt);
        else
            newValues.push(array[i]*array[i]);
    }
    return newValues;
}

var a = [3,4,5,9,7,16,36,11];
console.log('Input : ' + a);
console.log('Output: ' + squareOrSquareRoot(a));
```

Comment: To put everything in one line doesn't make your code better, faster, more readable. Human Readability is the main issue of code.

Comment: @webdeb better? :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am going through your code now. It uses the conditional ternary operator, which I didn't know about until your answer and webdeb's answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response without ternary expression. 

1. Why are you doing this? 
newValues.push(array[i]);
I want to add the square root value (var sqrt)  to newValues array.

2. Why are you doing this? 
newValues.push(array[i]*array[i]);
Should I remove var initial? Is so, why?

Comment: @thisOne yes the logic is different than what you are looking for, i have submitted an edit it should be updated one its reviewed.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is flawed. Change

```
Number.isInteger(sqrt) == 'true'
```

to

```
Number.isInteger(sqrt) == true
```

`Number.isInteger` returns a boolean not a string. Also the second else if is redundant, if isInteger returns false then just execute the else part rather than checking again. 
Finally you need to return `newValues` not `newArray`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, there's no need for the '== true'.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but I personally find that the code becomes easier to maintain and bugs spotted when its written out explicitly like this, its a readability and maintenance preference though.

Answer (score -2):

Even better to not use a for loop, instead an `array.map` is totally applicable.

```
  function squareOrSquareRoot(array) {
    return array.map(function(int) {
      var sqrt = Math.sqrt(int);
      return Number.isInteger(sqrt) ? sqrt : int * int;
    })
  }
```

`Array.map` maps each item to the given function and returns at the end a new array.

Comment: @Scimonster it isn't but in this situation the `Array.map` is a much better and simpler solution. Because you want to iterate over all items and return an output array only based on the given one..

Comment: @webdeb 'I am just learning how to code and I am working on fundamentals right now' - OP. Why do you think that he will understand mapping or ternary expression?

Comment: Yes, I do not understand mapping or the last line. But I like how simple it is.

Comment: @thisOne It is simple and clean but learn basics first, you will get into mapping and everything later. Good luck

Comment: @webdeb return is not good also, you should return sqrt : int*int as OP mentioned above.

Comment: Mapping is basically a for each loop, but it creates a function for every item, which makes it slow.

Comment: 1. Fixed the return statement, int * int. thanks.

2. Yeah you should know the basics, definitely

3. The performance difference is not significant for 99,99% apps, but code readability is. First, make it work. Measure, and then apply performance when you need it. Premature optimisation over code readability is stupid.

Comment: @RickardElimää you are wrong, the function will be reused, its BS that it is slow.. really

Comment: Yay, I'm in a for-loop vs map argument. Noone can win!

https://jsperf.com/map-vs-native-for-loop/7

And if you want to use for loop and make it readable, refactor the loop and name that method that loops so it's readable. That said, for this example, none of this is really important, but it's good to at least discussed and weighted the different alternatives.

Comment: @RickardElimää well the for loop is a native function which shows the underlying concepts. It also offers you much more precision and features, a lot more control. But readability is during development much more important, performance is what you can apply afterwards when you have to.